# Disable di:compile PHP Comments check in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, di, setup-di-compile

I Upgraded to Magento 2.2.2 and now di:compile checks if `@params` comments for constructors are correct. I have many modules where the comments are incorrect but the params are correct, so I want to disable this feature or workaround somehow.

Is there a solution for this problem, or do I have to go through all the plugins and fix this?

Error messages look like:

```
Incompatible argument type: Required type: ... Actual type: ...
```

My PHP Version is 7.0.21 so that should not be the problem.

Comment: You have to go through all the plugins and fix this.

Comment: This is what I came up with. I just deleted all the comments from 3rd party modules constructors and now it works.

Comment: Ok. Please post answer here with all explanation. It will help others.